# How to Unit Test MatBottomSheet

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am getting an error that DependentComponent's properties are not set.

I want to ignore calling DependentComponent - `this._bottomSheet.open(DependentComponent)`, but not sure how to achieve that.

I guess `mockBottomSheetRef.open.and.callThrough();` is not the correct way of doing this. I need help here.

.ts

```js
constructor(private _bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<DependentComponent>) { }

showOverlay() {
    this._bottomSheet.open(DependentComponent, {
      panelClass: 'search-container'
    });
 }
```

spec.ts

```js
  mockBottomSheetRef = { open: jasmine.createSpy('open') };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      MyComponent
      DependentComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      TestModule
    ],
    providers: [
      { provide: MatBottomSheetRef, useValue: mockBottomSheetRef }
    ],
  })
  .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [DependentComponent] } })
  .compileComponents();



  it('should', () => {
    mockBottomSheetRef.open.and.callThrough(); 
    component.showOverlay();
    expect(mockBottomSheetRef.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: May you please add the code of `this._bottomSheet` creation? most likely it is in the constructor.

Comment: @IAfanasov I added the constructor

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not provide an answer. I hope my thoughts would be of use. I believe you don't need the line `mockBottomSheetRef.open.and.callThrough();` and no need to add `DependentComponent` into declarations. It is because `mockBottomSheetRef = { open: jasmine.createSpy('open') };` would mock the actual behaviour of the `this._bottomSheet.open` and would not call original method so that no one would try to instantiate `DependentComponent`. The only possible issue I can think of is the generic argument of the injection token `MatBottomSheetRef<DependentComponent>`.

Comment: I tried that, it's erroring out. DependentComponent properties are not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typo is the worst bug :D

`this._bottomSheet.open` - it is **MatBottomSheet** while the mock provided for the **MatBottomSheetRef**. notice the `Ref` in the end.

It should work like this:

```js
  mockBottomSheet = { open: jasmine.createSpy('open') };

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      MyComponent
      DependentComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      TestModule
    ],
    providers: [
      { provide: MatBottomSheet, useValue: mockBottomSheet }
    ],
  })
  .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [DependentComponent] } })
  .compileComponents();


  it('opens bottom sheet when `showOverlay` executed', () => {
    component.showOverlay();
    expect(mockBottomSheet.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```